# OS confusing eMMC device for SD card device - how to fix using udev

Tags: udev, hardware, sd-card, mmc

Busybox Linux running on an ARM Cortex A7 processor from NXP.

The board has an SD card slot and also an `eMMC` chip that can be used for storage.  The device is booting from nor flash.

Strangely, when the SD card is inserted, we cannot mount the `eMMC` drive and we get a partition missing error.  After a reboot the problem goes away.  Removing the SD card has the same sort of issue but this time we cannot mount the `eMMC` partition and get a failed to mount error.

So this got us to thinking that the `eMMC` device was being confused with the SD card when mounting the `eMMC` failed.

If you run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/mmcblk2` (`mmcblk2` is the `eMMC` device) in the failing scenario we get:

```
ATTRS{type}=="SD"
```

But when the mount works we get reported as:

```
ATTRS{type}=="MMC"
```

So we suspect that the OS is confusing the SD card device for the `MMC` device.

Can I force `ATTRS{type}=="MMC"`?

If so how would I do that?

Or is there a better alternative way to fix this?

additional notes

```
dmesg when we can't mount eMMC partition 1
[    1.981630] mmc2: MAN_BKOPS_EN bit is not set
[    1.996222] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[    2.003347] mmc2: new DDR MMC card at address 0001
[    2.004444] mmcblk2: mmc2:0001 R1J57L 13.8 GiB 
[    2.006353] mmcblk2boot0: mmc2:0001 R1J57L partition 1 16.0 MiB
[    2.006672] mmcblk2boot1: mmc2:0001 R1J57L partition 2 16.0 MiB
[    2.006912] mmcblk2rpmb: mmc2:0001 R1J57L partition 3 128 KiB
[    2.010135]  mmcblk2: p1
```

dmesg when mounting of eMMC works:

```
[    1.852533] mmc2: new DDR MMC card at address 0001
[    1.853202] mmcblk2: mmc2:0001 R1J57L 13.8 GiB 
[    1.853364] mmcblk2boot0: mmc2:0001 R1J57L partition 1 16.0 MiB
[    1.853544] mmcblk2boot1: mmc2:0001 R1J57L partition 2 16.0 MiB
[    1.853697] mmcblk2rpmb: mmc2:0001 R1J57L partition 3 128 KiB
[    1.856437]  mmcblk2: p1
```

difference is that in non-working get: mmc2: MAN_BKOPS_EN bit is not set.  BKOPS is background operations - an eMMC performance feature.  No idea how linked with this issue.

lsblk:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk2rpmb  179:32   0  128K  0 disk 
mmcblk2boot0 179:16   0   16M  1 disk 
mmcblk2boot1 179:24   0   16M  1 disk 
mmcblk0      179:0    0  3.8G  0 disk 
`-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  3.8G  0 part 
mmcblk2      179:8    0 13.8G  0 disk 
`-mmcblk2p1  179:9    0 13.8G  0 part
```

mmcblk2 is the eMMC and mmcblk0 is the SD-card.

running udevadm info on mmcblk0, the SD-card.

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/mmcblk0
ATTRS{type}=="SD"
```

Comment: Do you use the eMMC in 8-bit-mode? (Because otherwise what is the difference between MMC and SD anyhow?) How are your interfaces configured, DeviceTree? What does `dmesg` say on SDcard insert and eject?

Comment: @Philippos unfortunately we cannot add/remove sd-card while running.